# How to get a sequence string per row from 2 columns in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the following data structure:

[image]

The columns "s" and "d" are indicating the transition of the object in column "x". What I want to do is get a transition string per object present in column "x". E.g. with a "new" column as follows:

[image]

Is there a good way to do it using PySpark?

I tried the following PySpark code using `udf`, but it does not work:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_distinct
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

create_transition = udf(lambda x: "->".join([i[0] for i in groupby(x)]))

df= df\
      .withColumn('list', F.concat(df['s'], F.lit(','), df['d']))\
      .groupBy('x').agg(F.collect_list('list').alias('list2'))\
      .withColumn("list3", create_transition("list2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If real values in columns "s" and "d" go in ascending order, then, using window partitions, you can:

- extract the `first` value from column "s"
- extract all the values from column "d"
- `array_union` all the extracted values
- `array_sort` and `array_join` into a string

```py
w = W.partitionBy('x')
arr = F.array_union(F.array(F.first('s').over(w)), F.collect_list('d').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('new', F.array_join(F.array_sort(arr), '->'))
```

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a',  1,  2),
     ('a',  2,  4),
     ('a',  4,  8),
     ('a',  8,  9),
     ('b',  5, 11),
     ('b', 11, 12)],
    ['x', 's', 'd'])

w = W.partitionBy('x')
arr = F.array_union(F.array(F.first('s').over(w)), F.collect_list('d').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('new', F.array_join(F.array_sort(arr), '->'))

df.show()
# +---+---+---+-------------+
# |  x|  s|  d|          new|
# +---+---+---+-------------+
# |  a|  1|  2|1->2->4->8->9|
# |  a|  2|  4|1->2->4->8->9|
# |  a|  4|  8|1->2->4->8->9|
# |  a|  8|  9|1->2->4->8->9|
# |  b|  5| 11|    5->11->12|
# |  b| 11| 12|    5->11->12|
# +---+---+---+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, the method works well! Exactly what I was looking for, and thanks for the step-by-step explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this spark.sql

```
spark.sql(s"""
with t1 ( select 'a' x ,  1 s,  2 d union all 
          select 'a',  2,  4 union all 
          select 'a',  4,  8 union all
          select 'a',  8,  9 union all
          select 'b',  5, 11 union all
          select 'b', 11, 12 ) ,
   t2 ( select x, collect_list(s) s, collect_list(d) d  from t1 group by x ),
   t3 ( select x, array_sort(array_union(s, d)) sd from t2 )
   select b.x , concat_ws('->',sd) new, s,d from t3 a 
    join t1 b on a.x=b.x 
    order by b.x,s

""").show(false)

+---+-------------+---+---+
|x  |new          |s  |d  |
+---+-------------+---+---+
|a  |1->2->4->8->9|1  |2  |
|a  |1->2->4->8->9|2  |4  |
|a  |1->2->4->8->9|4  |8  |
|a  |1->2->4->8->9|8  |9  |
|b  |5->11->12    |5  |11 |
|b  |5->11->12    |11 |12 |
+---+-------------+---+---+
```

Breaking up:

```
spark.sql(s"""  select 'a' x ,  1 s,  2 d union all 
          select 'a',  2,  4 union all 
          select 'a',  4,  8 union all
          select 'a',  8,  9 union all
          select 'b',  5, 11 union all
          select 'b', 11, 12 
""").createOrReplaceTempView("input")

spark.sql(s"""
with t2 ( select x, collect_list(s) s, collect_list(d) d  from input group by x ),
     t3 ( select x, array_sort(array_union(s, d)) sd from t2 )
   select b.x , concat_ws('->',sd) new, s,d from t3 a 
    join input b on a.x=b.x 
    order by b.x,s
""").show(false)
```

Comment: This works well, but we need a generic solution, independent of the content of the data and the number of rows. The solution from ZygD above worked best. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: This is generic solution only, I just hardcoded the input values inside t1 table, you can take make it separate as well

Comment: I have given a break up for understanding, SQL is portable style than remembering those df steps. Looks like you are not familiar with the with() style of SQL, so you may not appreciate it